# URLs to specific answers scroll a little too far

Tags: bug, top-bar

When you click a link to a specific answer, it appears the scroll position is set a couple lines too far down.  This has been going on for a while (weeks?), but I'm pretty sure it hasn't always been a problem.

I'm not a web-UI person, but I believe the problem is the top bar overlaps the top of the page rather than being a separate entity that lives north of the scrollable region.  Thus, the browser does scroll to position the `<a name="number"></a>` element at the top of the browser window, but the first couple line of text are covered by the top bar.

For example, when I click on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619482/what-techniques-to-avoid-conditional-branching-do-you-know/1645178#1645178), I see:

[image: top two lines of direct-to-answer link are covered by the top navigation bar]

Note that the top two lines of the answer are not in view.

Arguably, this is just a slight annoyance.  But for folks finding their way to Stack Overflow for the first time from a search engine result, it would make a better impression to get the scroll position just right.

In case it matters ...

Chrome 116.0.5845.141 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable), Windows 10 Version 22H2 (Build 19045.3324)

Comment: See also [this old bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312508/323179) (fixed)

Comment: I see that it does scroll a little more but then given a fraction of a second more it scrolls back to correct position. What I've noticed it doesn't cope well with is the user beginning to scroll just as it finishes up. It also doesn't work well with what I assume is comments being loaded up which causes it to miss the mark by quite a lot

Comment: No repro for me. Also Chrome on Win 10, two different machines.

Comment: "Easy Workaround" = No Repro when using the 'uBlock' Script I had posted [here](/a/416973/3799241). // Repro if I disable the Script, especially the part about setting back the 'Top Bar' to "unsticky".. // [FCI: FF v116.0.3_x64 + Win10_Pro_x64_22H2, + Logged in to 'SO'.]

Comment: Interesting, I can repro only by going to the address bar then hitting enter again. Initial navigation works fine for me, I only end up in the wrong place if I navigate after the page has already loaded fully

Comment: I tried again in Incognito mode, just to ensure it wasn't some extension, and it made no difference.  However, I did discover that the problem occurs _only_ when I'm signed in.